# What's wrong with android dao error?

Tags: android, android-room

I build my android project, but messages output this following error,
this error from android dao.

`Error:(31, 19) error: mismatched input 'fromJson' expecting {<EOF>, ';', ',', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXCEPT, K_EXPLAIN, K_FROM, K_GROUP, K_INSERT, K_INTERSECT, K_LIMIT, K_ORDER, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UNION, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WHERE, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which would include the source code to the class that is triggering this error (or, at least, the `fromJson()` method).

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, my gson class triggering this error, I rename this class

Comment: @CommonsWare I rename this class also doesn't work....

Answer (score 6):

It is probably a Syntax error in your SQL Query.

Make sure that when you are concatenating your Query (String) that you put a space at the end of each line.

```
@Query("SELECT c.username, c.first_name, c.last_name, r1.water_amount AS waterAmountLastMonth " +
       "FROM citizen c " +
       "INNER JOIN report r1 ON r1.date_month = :dateMonth " +
       "ORDER BY c.first_name ASC")
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I wrote the wrong query. My query was -

```
 @Query("SELECT * " +
                DbConstants.TABLE_MEDICINE + " WHERE " + DbConstants.MEDICINE_ID + " = (:id)")
        fun read(id: Long): LiveData<Medicine>
 /*Notice here,I missed "FROM" query in the query.*/
```

Correct query was -

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " +
            DbConstants.TABLE_MEDICINE + " WHERE " + DbConstants.MEDICINE_ID + " = (:id)")
    fun read(id: Long): LiveData<Medicine> /*Include "FROM" now.
```

So if anyone get this kind of error,then first check if your SQL query is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but with slightly different cause. It was still a wrong `@Query`, but the issue was with my table name. I had `-` in the table name, which was invalid. Removing it fixed the issue.